# Let $a$ and $b$ be roots of $x^2-7x+2$. Find the value of $a^6 + b^6$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, quadratics

> Let $a$ and $b$ be roots of $x^2-7x+2$. Find the value of $a^6 + b^6$.

Answer:

$a+b = 7, ab = 2$

$$\begin{align}
(a+b)^6 &= a^6 + 6a^5b+15a^4b^2+20a^3b^3+15a^2b^4+6ab^5+b^6 \\[4pt]
a^6 + b^6 &= (a+b)^6 -  (6a^5b+15a^4b^2+20a^3b^3+15a^2b^4+6ab^5) \\
&= (a+b)^6 - (6ab(a^4 + b^4) + 15a^2b^2 (a^2 + b^2) + 20(ab)^3)
\end{align}$$

now,
$$\begin{align}
a^4 + b^4 &= (a+b)^4 - (4a^3b + 6a^2b^2 + 4ab^3) \\
&= (a+b)^4 - (4ab(a^2 + b^2) + 6(ab)^2) \\
&= (a+b)^4 - (4ab((a + b)^2 - 2ab) + 6(ab)^2) \\
&= 7^4 - (4(2)(7^2 - 2(2)) + 6(2)^2) \\
&= 2017
\end{align}$$

so

$$\begin{align} 
&\phantom{=}\; (a+b)^6 - (6ab(a^4 + b^4) + 15a^2b^2 (a^2 + b^2) + 20(ab)^3)\\
&= 7^6 - (6\cdot2\cdot(2017) + 15(2)^2 (7^2 - 2(2)) + 20(2)^3) \\
&= 90585
\end{align}$$
correct?

Comment: Alternatively, let $x_n = a^n + b^n$. Then $x_{n+2}=7x_{n+1}-2x_n$. Start with $x_0=2$ and $x_1=7$.

Answer (score 15):

Holy unsimplified long expressions Batman.
$$
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2
&=(a+b)^2-2ab\\
&=45
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
a^6+b^6 
&= (a^2+b^2)^3-3(ab)^2(a^2+b^2)\\
&= (a^2+b^2)((a^2+b^2)^2-3(ab)^2)\\
&= 45\times(45^2-12)\\
&=90585\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Where does the first step of $ a^6+b^6=(a^2+b^2)^3−3(ab)^2(a^2+b^2)$ come from?

Comment: @RobVolgman it comes from expanding $(a^2+b^2)^3$ and then rearranging the terms.

Answer (score 5):

For either root of the equation:

- $x^2 = 7x - 2$
- $x^4 = (7x - 2)^2 = 49 x^2 - 28 x + 4 = 49(7x-2) - 28 x + 4 = 315 x - 94$
- $x^6 = (7x - 2)(315 x - 94) = 2205 x^2 - 1288 x + 188 = 14147 x - 4222$

It follows that $\,a^6+b^6 = 14147 (a+b) - 2 \cdot 4222 = 14147 \cdot 7 - 8444 = 90585\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ The underlying idea in the above is based on the Euclidean division:

$$
x^6 = (x^4 + 7 x^3 + 47 x^2 + 315 x + 2111) \cdot(x^2 - 7 x + 2) + (14147 x - 4222)
$$

Then substituting $x = a,b$ the product is zero, which leaves only the remainder to evaluate, and adding the two equalities gives the same result as in the last line of the answer.

The shortcut here was to derive the remainder directly, without doing the full long division and calculating the quotient, which is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You have the correct answer, but here's a shorter way.

From Vieta's formulas, $a + b = 7$ and $ab = 2$

$$a^2 + b^2 = (a + b)^2 - 2ab = 7^2 - 2(2) = 49-4 = 45$$
$$a^4 + b^4 = (a^2 + b^2)^2 - 2(ab)^2 =45^2 - 2(2^2) = 2017$$
$$a^6 + b^6 = (a^4 + b^4)(a^2 + b^2) - (ab)^2(a^2 + b^2) = 2017 \times 45 - 2^2(45) = 90585$$

Answer (score 3):

Why work so hard?  From the quadratic formula we have:

$\{ a,b \} = \left\{ \frac{7-\sqrt{41}}{2}, \frac{7+\sqrt{41}}{2} \right\}$ so $a^6 + b^6 = 90585$.

---

My goodness!!!  A downvote on a simple, clear, correct answer.

Well, if the approach demands that the solution be done "by hand"—which was *NOT* part of the problem statement!— then here:

$$a^6 + b^6 = \frac{1}{2^6} \left[ ((7 - \sqrt{41})^2 )^3 + ((7 + \sqrt{41})^2 )^3\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{64} \left[ (90 - 14 \sqrt{41})^3 + (90 + 14 \sqrt{41})^3\right]$$

Now cancel the terms with odd powers of $(14 \sqrt{41})$ (because they have opposite signs in the pairs), leaving

$$\frac{1}{64} \left[ 2 \cdot 90^3 + 6 \cdot 90 \cdot 14^2 \cdot 41\right] = 90585$$

Satisfied?

Comment: This was probably a contest problem, so computing the powers of those roots by hand would be extremely time consuming.

Comment: @AlannRosas:  If so, the OP should state that as a condition.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the problem is easy enough to do without taking roots.

Comment: This seems as simple as any other approach! +1

Answer (score 3):

A better way to handle this is to observe the factorization
$$a^6 + b^6 = (a^2 + b^2)(a^4 - a^2 b^2 + b^4),$$ from which we observe
$$a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab,$$ and
$$a^4 - a^2 b^2 + b^4 = (a^2 + b^2)^2 - 3a^2 b^2.$$

Since we know that $$x^2 - 7x + 2 = (x - a)(x - b) = x^2 - (a+b)x + ab,$$ it follows that $a+b = 7$ and $ab = 2$.  So we just put everything together:

$$a^2 + b^2 = 7^2 - 2(2) = 49 - 4 = 45,$$
$$a^4 - a^2 b^2 + b^4 = (45)^2 - 3(2)^2 = 2013,$$

therefore
$$a^6 + b^6 = 45(2013) = 90585.$$

Comment: How do you observe the second equation from the first one?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Our answers are nearly identical.  If you are asking about the third equation in my answer, that is simply $$a^4 - a^2 b^2 + b^4 = a^4 + 2a^2 b^2 + b^4 - 3 a^2 b^2.$$  We want to get something like $(a^2  +b^2)^2$, and to do that, we add and subtract $3a^2 b^2$.

Comment: No, why does it say "from which we observe" ?

Comment: @SuzuHirose The second and third equations are not consequences of the first:  "from which we observe" simply means "following the factorization, we also have...."

Answer (score 3):

From Vieta’s rules, $a+b=7, ab=2$. $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)=(a+b)((a+b)^2-3ab)= 7(49-2\cdot 3)=7\cdot 43=301 $$ Again, $$(a^3+b^3)^2=a^6+b^6+2a^3b^3$$$$301^2=a^6+b^6+2(2)^3$$ so $$a^6+b^6=301^2-16=90585. $$

Comment: That's probably the best answer so far if you have to do the arithmetic on paper, as seems to be implied elsewhere in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, let $x_n = a^n + b^n$. Then $x_{n+2}=7x_{n+1}-2x_n$ and so we get

$x_0=2$

$x_1=7$

$x_2=7x_1-2x_0=45$

$x_3=7x_2-2x_1=301$

$x_4=7x_3-2x_2=2017$

$x_5=7x_4-2x_3=13517$

$x_6=7x_5-2x_4=90585$

This is easy to do by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Given $a$ and $b$ be the roots of the equation $x^2-7x+2=0$. Sum of roots, $$a+b=7$$
Product of roots, $$ab=2.$$
Now, $(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab=49-8=41$.

$\Rightarrow a-b=\pm\sqrt{41}$.
Taking $a-b=\sqrt{41}$.
On solving equation $a+b=7$ and $a-b=\sqrt{41}$.
We obtain, $a=\frac{7+\sqrt{41}}{2}$ and $b=\frac{7-\sqrt{41}}{2}.$

Comment: You haven't finished the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

What the hey, I'll toss in one more (there are plenty of ways to work with the binomials, and some of the other answers already given are ones I'd have tried first):

We need $$ \ a + b \ = \ 7 \ \ , \ \ a - b \ = \ \sqrt{\Delta} \ = \ \sqrt{41} \ \ , \ \ ab \ = \ 2  \ \ , $$ $$ a^2 + b^2 \ = \ (a + b)^2 - 2ab \ = \ 49 - 4 \ = \ 45 \ \ , $$
as already presented. We can write
$$ (a + b)^6 \ + \ (a - b)^6 \ \ = \ \ 2a^6 \ + \ 2b^6 \ + \ 30·(a^4b^2 \ + \ a^2b^4) $$ $$ = \ \ 2·(a^6 \ + \ b^6) \ + \ 30·(ab)^2·(a^2 \ + \ b^2) \ \ = \ \ 2·(a^6 \ + \ b^6) \ + \ 30·2^2·45 $$

$$ = \ \ 7^6 \ + \ 41^3 \  \ = \ \ 49^3 \ + \ 41^3 \ \ . $$

If we need to do this "by hand", we have $ \ 49^3  +  41^3 \ = \ (49 + 41)·(49^2 - 49·41 + 41^2) \ \ , $ for which we can use little "binomial tricks" to produce $ \ (50 - 1)^2 \ - \ (50 - 1)·(40 + 1) \ + \ (40 + 1)^2 $ $ = \ 2401 - 2009 + 1681 \ = \ 2073 \ \Rightarrow \ 49^3  +  41^3 \ = \ 90·2073 \ = \ 207,300 - 20,730 $ $ = \  186,570 \ \ . $  We also have $ \ 30·4·45 \ = \ 6·4·15^2 \ = \ 6·(4·225) \ =  \ 6·900 \ = \ 5400 \ \ . $

Thus,
$$ 2·(a^6 \ + \ b^6) \ \ = \ \ [ \ (a + b)^6 \ - \ (a - b)^6 \ ] \ - \ 30·(ab)^2·(a^2 \ + \ b^2) $$
$$ = \ \ 186,570 \ - \ 5400 \ \ = \ \ 181,170 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a^6 \ + \ b^6 \ \ = \ \ 90,585 \ \ . $$

[This is somewhere between what you started out doing and **Dan**'s method.]